# Let z and w are two complex number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let z and w are two complex number. Prove that

> $$\left|\frac{z-w}{1-z ̅w}\right| =1 \text{ if } |z|=1 \text{ but } w \neq z$$

Comment: @T.Eskin i don't know how to start

Comment: @user319783 Suppose $Z=Z_1+Z_2i$ and $W=W_1+W_2i$ then use definition of the modulus.

Comment: The claim isn't true... Let $z=i,w=0$ and you get $\displaystyle \left|\frac{z-w}{1-z-w}\right|=\left|\frac{i}{1-i}\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ne 1$.

Comment: How can z's absolute value be equal to 1 if it is a complex number? Forgive me if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Galc, he/she stated that both w and z are complex numbers... how is 0 a complex number? I'm not insulting or anything, I don't know all about complex numbers and the only way I can think that 0 is a complex number was if it was defined as 0i, but then that takes away from the point of being a complex number as it can be visualized in the real number plane.

Comment: @GilKeidar The real numbers are all numbers of the form $x+iy$, with $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. $0$ is, by that definition a complex number.

Comment: And for absolute value, the absolute value of a complex number, $\left| z \right| = z * \bar{z}$. Thus, it will always output a real number.

Comment: @Nikolas Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong notation

Comment: @NikolasWojtalewicz You also need to take the square root on the right hand side to get the actual norm of $|z|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\left|\frac{z-w}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|=1 \text{ if } |z|=1 \text{ but } w\neq z \text{ and } w,z\in\mathbb{C}$$

Notice:

- $$\overline{z}=\frac{|z|^2}{z}=\frac{1^2}{z}=\frac{1}{z}$$

  ---

$$\left|\frac{z-w}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|=\left|\frac{z-w}{1-\frac{1}{z}\cdot w}\right|=\left|\frac{z-w}{1-\frac{w}{z}}\right|=\left|\frac{z-w}{\frac{z}{z}-\frac{w}{z}}\right|=$$
$$\left|\frac{z-w}{\frac{z-w}{z}}\right|=\frac{\left|z-w\right|}{\left|\frac{z-w}{z}\right|}=\frac{|z-w|}{\frac{|z-w|}{|z|}}=\frac{|z-w|}{1}\cdot\frac{|z|}{|z-w|}=\frac{|z|}{1}=|z|=1$$

Answer (score 2):

If $|z|=1$ then $|z|^2=z\bar z=1\implies |z\bar z|=|z||\bar z|=|\bar z| = 1$

Applying this result to $|z-w|$ gives

$|z-w|=|z-\frac{w\bar z}{\bar z}|=\frac{|z\bar z-w\bar z|}{|\bar z|}=\frac{|1-w\bar z|}{|\bar z|}=|1-w\bar z|$

Since $w\ne z$, $w\bar z\ne z\bar z=1\implies |1-w\bar z|\ne 0$

Therefore, we can divide both sides by $|1-w\bar z|$ to get $\frac{|z-w|}{|1-w\bar z|}=1$

Answer (score 1):

As Galc127 noted in the comments, it isn't true. For example, take $z=i$, $w=0$. Then your expression returns $\frac 1 {\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: If $w=0$ then $\frac{|z-w|}{|1-\bar zw|}=\frac{|z|}{|1|}=|z|$ which is $1$ for $z=i$

Comment: Whoops, thought there was subtraction between $z$ and $w$ on the bottom. Actually, the original question did have subtraction there.

Comment: he edited the question. there was actually a subtraction

Comment: Soory, it was because i was using phone when i write this question

Comment: @Nikolas Wojtalewicz This didn't provide answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to show that $|z-w|^{2}=|1-\bar{z}w|^{2}$. Note that
\begin{align*}
|z-w|^{2} &=(z-w)\overline{(z-w)}=(z-w)(\bar{z}-\bar{w})=|z|^{2}-z\bar{w}-w\bar{z}+|w|^{2}.
\end{align*}
And you can show similarly that
\begin{align*}
|1-\bar{z}w|^{2}&=|z|^{2}-z\bar{w}-\bar{z}w+|w|^{2}
\end{align*}
by using $|z|^{2}=1$. It is an easy computation and I'll leave that part for you to fill in.

Comment: There is no square  there in.

Comment: @user41736 If $z=a+ib$ then $z\bar{z}=a^{2}+b^{2}$. So $|z|^{2}=z\bar{z}$.

Comment: look at the question.

Comment: @user41736. Maybe there's something you're misunderstanding or I'm being unclear. If the statement is true for the squares, by square rooting you get the statement of the question. That's why I wrote "it is sufficient to show..". And with squares you can open the actual norms. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: thank you very much. This will help me a lot

Comment: @snssnm. No problem. I'm glad I was able to help.